# KeystoneJS watch:lint is not in your gulpfile

Tags: node.js, gulp, keystonejs

I'm trying to generate a website scaffold with KeystoneJS. I was able to generate the files. 
But starting nodejs with `npm start` leads to the following Error:

```
[10:17:29] Using gulpfile /home/daniel/Projects/keystonetest/gulpfile.js
[10:17:29] Task 'watch:lint' is not in your gulpfile
[10:17:29] Please check the documentation for proper gulpfile formatting

npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-22-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "start"
npm ERR! node v5.11.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.8.6
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! keystonetest@0.0.0 start: `gulp`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
```

I'm new to Gulp. I searched for the Meaning of `watch:lint` but did not found something about it. As far as I know the task's looking for changes in my project.

My gulp.js:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var watch = require('gulp-watch');
var shell = require('gulp-shell')

var paths = {
  'src':['./models/**/*.js','./routes/**/*.js', 'keystone.js','package.json']
};

gulp.task('runKeystone', shell.task('node keystone.js'));
gulp.task('watch', [
 'watch:lint'
]);

gulp.task('default', ['watch', 'runKeystone']);
```

Also one of the node modules (chokidar/fsevents) was not installed due to missing compatibility to my OS (Ubuntu 16.04). As far as I know it's not needed.

What I've tried:

- Reinstalled KeystoneJS
- Created Scaffold multiple times
- Searched the error message

Any idea what I could try?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Because you have not defined `lint` task.

Comment: Tank you. I thought of something like that. But why does Keystone not create a lint task?

Comment: Hello. I have the same issue.

Comment: Hi. I have removed the watch task for now. A colleague of mine has also faced this problem.

Comment: An Issue was opened on GitHub. If someone is interested in this: https://github.com/keystonejs/generator-keystone/issues/193

Answer (score 2):

I noticed that in the template for gulp the task [was changed recently](http://%20https://github.com/keystonejs/generator-keystone/blob/master/app/templates/_gulpfile.js) but the package in npm has not been updated.
Try editing the gulpfile.js and remove the line (and the previous semicolon):

```
'watch:lint'
```

It should work afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

I'm just facing this problem right now, and it just seems that both grunt and gulp files are not ready for use.

If you dont need gulp and just want to test Keystone, you can set 'none' in yeoman choice for automation tool, or just use `node keystone.js` (or nodemon, if you have it installed) instead of `npm start`, to avoid this problem until you will use gulp in a right way.

You could also update the package.json to remove the "scripts" assignment, in order to ask `npm start` use `node keystone.js`.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you for the additional information. Choosing 'none' leads to another error. I'll use my method by removing the gulp task. Using `node keystone.js` does work, too.